# Firebase Ecosystem - Security and Cost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the Firebase ecosystem, for example in Cloud-Firestore, **financial cost** is highly dependent on factors such as **document reads**.

- Is there anything protecting us from hostiles sending large numbers of read requests directly to our Firestore (circumventing our app) in order to **drive our cost up**?
- Does the Firebase platform somehow recognise this and filter it out, or would we simply have to pay if this happened to us?

Clarification: Let's assume our Firestore security rules are such, that there are certain read requests which can be performed by anyone (`allow read;`). Consider for example a HackerNews type application, where anyone can list posts *(no authentication required)*.

Comment: Are you talking about succesfull read requests or just attempted (and failed/rejected) reads. I don't know if it makes a difference but it might be better to be specific.

Comment: I was thinking about successful read request, but it would be interesting to know the answer for both successful and unsuccessful read requests.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore is designed to enable you to scale without experiencing an outage due to overload. We do enable you to set [daily spending caps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/usage#limits) using the App Engine daily spending limit which can help prevent unexpected runaway costs.

There are a few other strategies to help control for this as well, such as using Firebase Auth and requiring users to sign-in, or doing server-side rendering of read-only results.

Comment: Could you go into more detail regarding "doing server-side rendering of read-only results" ?

Comment: I just discovered that I am being charged for using the Firebase console. I filtered and bam, an extra 7000 reads.